# After upgrade AngularJS app to include Angular - marcoTask 'RequestAnimationFrame' exception

Tags: angularjs, angular, zonejs, angular-upgrade

We've upgrade a large AngularJS app to Angular. By upgrade I mean bootstrapping Angular app and then bootstrapping AngularJS.

Everything seems to work fine on Chrome but when using FireFox we get the following exception every so often:

```
macroTask 'requestAnimationFrame': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'.
```

This is the full stack-trace:

```
11:21:30.063 (showError): unhandled-exception-message Error: macroTask 'requestAnimationFrame': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'.
Stack trace:
Error: macroTask 'requestAnimationFrame': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'.
    at _transitionTo (zone.js:533)
    at Error (zone.js:182)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:499)
    at invoke (zone.js:488)
    at timer (zone.js:2040) 1 vendor.dll.js:41649:16
                consoleLog/< http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:41649:16
                LoggerInstance.prototype.invokeLogger http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:141191:9
                LoggerInstance.prototype.error http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:141156:9
                showError/< http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:138649:17
                processQueue http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:44000:37
                scheduleProcessQueue/< http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:44044:27
                $digest http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:45182:15
                UpgradeModule.prototype.bootstrap/initModule</</subscription< http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/app.js:5385:101
                EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn< http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:5329:36
                SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:20411:13
                SafeSubscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:20358:17
                Subscriber.prototype._next http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:20298:9
                Subscriber.prototype.next http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:20262:13
                Subject.prototype.next http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:26393:17
                EventEmitter.prototype.emit http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:5303:54
                checkStable http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:5537:13
                onLeave http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:5616:5
                onInvokeTask http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/common.js:5566:17
                vendor</</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:169226:17
                vendor</</</Zone.prototype.runTask http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:168994:28
                vendor</</</ZoneTask.invokeTask http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:169301:24
                ZoneTask/this.invoke http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:169290:28
                scheduleTask/target[XHR_LISTENER] http://localhost:9090/ui/generated/webpack/vendor.dll.js:171726:25
```

Comment: The only solution I've found for now is to use DowngradeModule instead of UpgradeModule.